# Git: Why are there files appearing from another branch in my brand-new branches?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch and pushed it to Github and created a Pull Request. I noticed there were a bunch of files from another branch in there.

So, I closed the PR, checkout my master branch, updated it from master and created a brand new branch. Before touching any files I ran `git status` which predictably returned no changes. I then, as an experiment, pushed this empty branch up to master on Github and created a new PR. The PR had the same extra files attached to it.

Would anyone know what's going on? Why are files from another branch attaching themselves to my new branch?

Steps I've taken:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b new-branch
git status //nothing here
git push origin new-branch

//open Github, create PR from new branch, see that it has a bunch of files in it already
```

Comment: What steps did you take to create the pull request?

Comment: As above - just went to Github, clicked on the branch and clicked the Create Pull Request button

Comment: Yes...but what is the source of that PR and what is the destination?  This is critical information for your question.

Comment: Sorry I suck at Git - don't know what those are

Comment: Then your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Ok, but why would the above work every other time?

Comment: The diff you are seeing with the extra files might be happening because the target is something other than `master`.  This is why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your `master` is *ahead of* `origin/master`.

That is, right after:

> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull origin master
> ```

if you run:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --boundary origin/master...master
```

what do you get as output?  (Note the three dots here, although two will get similar information.)  If something shows up here, the results you got might be expected.  You can also run:

```
git rev-list --count origin/master..master
```

(note two dots this time); if the output is not zero, all of this makes sense.

> ```
> git checkout -b new-branch
> ```

This creates the new name `new-branch` pointing to the same *commit* as your (regular, local) branch name `master`.  You probably wanted one pointing to the same *commit* as your `origin/master`.  If `origin/master` is selecting a different (older) commit than `master`, you've selected the wrong commit here.

> ```
> git status //nothing here
> ```

Since you just created `new-branch` there's nothing really of interest to report here.

> ```
> git push origin new-branch
> ```

This has your Git call up the Git over at `origin` (on GitHub), and asks them to create *their* name `branch` such that it selects the same commit as your name `branch`.  If that commit is ahead of their `master`—your `origin/master`–and you make a pull request now, that pull request will contain the commits that your `master` has, that their `master` lacks.